# Chrome e Opera não respeitam o cache

Tags: google-chrome, cache, header, opera

O Chrome e Opera (mesmo motor do primeiro) não respeita os headers `Cache-control` e `Expires`, quero dizer se for um link ou uma interação dentro da página **funciona normalmente**, aparece isto a frente:

[image: cache ok]

Mas se a requisição vier **dos favoritos do navegador** ele simplesmente ignora o cache:

[image: ignorou o cache]

É quase como se eu tivesse apertado F5 (ou talvez seja este mesmo o comportamento), no Firefox o problema não ocorre, somente no Chrome e Opera mesmo.

O código de teste foi este:

```php
<?php
$seconds = 360; // uma hora de cache

header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $seconds) . ' GMT', true);
header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=' . $seconds, true);
header('Pragma: max-age=' . $seconds, true);

$atual = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s');

//Ultima modificação é considerado a hora do acesso
header('Last-Modified: ' . $atual . ' GMT', true);
?>

<a href="pagina.php">Recarregar</a><br>

<?php echo $atual; ?>
```

> Isto não é um problema com PHP, só use ele para efetuar o teste com os headers

Existe alguma maneira de indicar para o navegador através dos headers que o cache deve *"ter preferencia"* ou isto é de fato um *Bug*?

Comment: É algum truque de programação por parte das pessoas que mantêm esses motores. Veja [esta pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245767/is-chrome-ignoring-control-cache-max-age) no SO matriz. A pergunta é de 2012, mas a resposta com mais votos tem atualizações de 2017.

Comment: @Renan obrigado, eu posso ter lido errado, mas a maior parte das respostas foi sobre uso de F5 e Ctrl+R, mas se eu fizer isto *"Another option is to copy the URL and paste it in the same tab or another tab."* que a primeira resposta sugere o cache também é ignorado. Talvez seja confusão minha, vou confirmar novamente e lhe aviso

Comment: @Renan eu entendi o que ocorre se eu estiver em uma página diferente e clicar no item do favoritos para levar a página em cache então ele funciona, mas se eu estiver na propria página com cache e clicar no favoritos ou "inputar" o endereço na barra ele vai notar que é o mesmo endereço e vai ignorar o cache pois provavelmente o navegador assume que vc quer atualizar a página atual.

Comment: Veja se tem algo útil nesse https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

Comment: Creio que não, a questão é o o que eu disse no comentário anterior ao Renan, eu só não formulei a resposta devido a falta de tempo de ler o source do Chromium.